# Limit @TexBoxFor digits to three and allow to type only numbers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have the following control in razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Persons, new { @class = "form-control w100", id = "cantPersonasBloque", @type = "number", maxvalue="3"})
```

I want to limit the digits to three and allow only number.
If I remove **@type = "number"** then maxvalue works and limits the digits to 3 but it's letting me add letters... However, if I put both together (type = number and maxvalue) it's limiting to number ok but not limiting the digits..

Is there a way to make both validations work?
I did a lot of research and testing but I didn't find the solution yet.

Thanks

Comment: What if you use **JQuery Mask** ? Just saw a similar case here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879008/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery-in-mvc5

Comment: Hi,is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `type="text"` with `maxlength` and `regular expression`:

```
<input asp-for="Persons" class="form-control w100" id = "cantPersonasBloque" type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d]/g,'')" maxlength="3" />
```

result:
[image]